# How to access the react app by with "url" having "/index.html" at the end?

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

I have my react app deployed by EC2 + Docker + Nginx.
What I want to do was accessing to this website by `domain/index.html` but I'm only able to browse it when there's no `/index.html`. I cannot figure how this works... I thought if I access by `domain/index.html` my index.html file will be accessed and get my react app turned on. Can someone give me an advice?

Below is a part in my webpack config file.

```
entry: './src/index.tsx',
output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    publicPath: '/',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I added below line in my react-router to solve this issue. I'm not sure this is the best option.

```
<Route exact path="/index.html" render={() => (<Redirect to="/" />)} />
```